# Convert SimpleXMLElement object to XML format in php

Tags: php, xml, yii2

one xml file view.xml

convert it into SimpleXMLElement Object after get parent node
it's child object need to convert into back in xml format in php

**

```
View.xml
```

**

```
> <cards name="country-cards" model="core_country" title="Country" >
>         <field name="name" />
>         <field name="code" />
>         <template><![CDATA[
>           <div class="span12"><strong>{{name}}</strong></div>             <div>
>             <div class="span8">
>               <span>{{name}}<br/>
>               {{code}}<br/></span>
>             </div></div>]]>
>         </template>
>     </cards>

**$xml = simplexml_load_file($xmlViewFilePath);**
```

> foreach ($xml as $key=>$value) {
>
> > **$value  want to convert back in to xml formate**
>
> }

**QUESTION:  Any other simple way to achieve SimpleXMLElement Object to XML parsing and store into Database without any I/O operation?**

**Already used the php conversion mechanism which results in output as null in database link below**

https://www.php.net/manual/en/simplexmlelement.asxml.php

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try Somthing like this..

```
 $doc = new DOMDocument();
    $doc->formatOutput = TRUE;
    $doc->loadXML($sxml->asXML());
    $xml = $doc->saveXML();
```

For more information check this link

https://www.php.net/manual/en/simplexmlelement.asxml.php